# What encoding could this be?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

Does this look as any known encoding to you? Thanks.

�'�h4n|��L�����O�����dx%'L��
�';j����L�����I�����Qp��
�(T`�8E�����8X8PRmBQiesY�l2�
���Q�C&��L  �a
�'נ��$���L��m���HҰ`�����!
�'�h4n|��L�����O�����dx%'L��
���Q�C&��L  �a
���Q�C&��L  �a
�'�h4n|��L�����O�����dx%'L��
�'נ��$���L��m���HҰ`�����!
�(T`    �8E�����8X8PRmBQiesY�l2�
�'נ��$���L��m���HҰ`�����$
���Q�C&��L  �a
�%;j�I�����X��/3��9��"Poa
�'�h4n|��L�����O�����dx%'L��
���Q�C&��L  �d

HEX:

```
7B22 7622 3A22 312E 3222 2C22 6D69 6422 
3A31 3032 322C 2269 6422 3A22 3138 3733 
3137 222C 2272 7373 6922 3A2D 3534 2C22 
7469 6D65 223A 3130 3234 2C22 6970 223A 
2231 3932 2E31 3638 2E31 3738 2E32 3422 
7D0D 0A0D 0AFE 2700 D413 6834 6E7C BE02 
0106 1AFF 4C00 0215 FDA5 0693 A4E2 4FB1 
AFCF C6EB 0764 7825 2713 4CB9 8E0D 0AFE 
2703 123B 6A1A 8498 B602 0106 1AFF 4C00 
0215 B5B1 82C7 EAB1 4988 AA99 B5C1 5170 
08D9 0001 0002 E10D 0AFE 2800 5460 09E1 
3845 CC02 0106 0303 9FFE 1716 9FFE 0238 
5838 5052 6D42 5169 6573 0000 0159 846C 
32E4 0D0A FE18 00F4 F951 BA43 26BE 0201 
1A0B FF4C 0009 0603 F100 0000 610D 0AFE 
2703 D7A0 948A 24A2 C602 0106 1AFF 4C00 
0215 E2C5 6DB5 DFFB 48D2 B060 D0F5 A710 
96E0 0000 0000 210D 0AFE 2700 D413 6834 
6E7C BE02 0106 1AFF 4C00 0215 FDA5 0693 
A4E2 4FB1 AFCF C6EB 0764 7825 2713 4CB9 
8E0D 0AFE 1800 F4F9 51BA 4326 BE02 011A 
0BFF 4C00 0906 03F1 0000 0061 0D0A FE18 
00F4 F951 BA43 26BE 0201 1A0B FF4C 0009 
0603 F100 0000 610D 0AFE 2700 D413 6834 
6E7C BE02 0106 1AFF 4C00 0215 FDA5 0693 
A4E2 4FB1 AFCF C6EB 0764 7825 2713 4CB9 
8E0D 0AFE 2703 D7A0 948A 24A2 C602 0106 
1AFF 4C00 0215 E2C5 6DB5 DFFB 48D2 B060 
D0F5 A710 96E0 0000 0000 210D 0AFE 2800 
5460 09E1 3845 CC02 0106 0303 9FFE 1716 
9FFE 0238 5838 5052 6D42 5169 6573 0000 
0159 846C 32E4 0D0A FE27 03D7 A094 8A24 
A2C3 0201 061A FF4C 0002 15E2 C56D B5DF 
FB48 D2B0 60D0 F5A7 1096 E000 0000 0024 
0D0A FE18 00F4 F951 BA43 26BE 0201 1A0B 
FF4C 0009 0603 F100 0000 610D 0AFE 2500 
123B 6A1A 8549 B702 0106 0303 F5FE 14FF 
D200 0101 1D58 90F4 2F33 8ED7 39BC AC22 
506F 610D 0AFE 2700 D413 6834 6E7C BE02 
0106 1AFF 4C00 0215 FDA5 0693 A4E2 4FB1 
AFCF C6EB 0764 7825 2713 4CB9 8E0D 0AFE 
1800 F4F9 51BA 4326 BB02 011A 0BFF 4C00 
0906 03F1 0000 0064 0D0A
```

Comment: What file extension did this file use?  Was it a binary / executable file, or an image file or something?

Comment: A hex or octal dump of the file is a lot more useful than this mess.

Comment: This is a string response from a BLE scanner + WiFi gateway. I assume it has several BLE advertising payloads encoded in it.

Comment: @PaulTomblin have a look at the HEX

Comment: This is mostly binary data, not encoded text. Neither of the tags (unicode, encoding, utf-8) apply. Please better describe where you got this data from and what you really want to achieve with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hex sequence 0D 0A occurs quite often, and specifically at the end.  That indicates to me a Windows-style CRLF linr endings, which is also a style used with multiple internet protocols (HTTP, SMTP, ...).  So, there's probably text hidden in there.  The first part is JSON-like encoding:

```
{"v":"1.2","mid":1022,"id":"187317","rssi":-54,"time":1024,"ip":"192.168.178.24"}
```

The 0D 0A sequence occurs quite often, but there are strings of null bytes and other such bytes that are not printable ASCII (and not clearly 8859-x).  It isn't a UTF encoding — neither UTF-8 nor UTF-16 nor UTF-32.

Converting the hex dump from the question into a file and then printing it with a different hex dump program yields:

```
0x0000: 7B 22 76 22 3A 22 31 2E 32 22 2C 22 6D 69 64 22   {"v":"1.2","mid"
0x0010: 3A 31 30 32 32 2C 22 69 64 22 3A 22 31 38 37 33   :1022,"id":"1873
0x0020: 31 37 22 2C 22 72 73 73 69 22 3A 2D 35 34 2C 22   17","rssi":-54,"
0x0030: 74 69 6D 65 22 3A 31 30 32 34 2C 22 69 70 22 3A   time":1024,"ip":
0x0040: 22 31 39 32 2E 31 36 38 2E 31 37 38 2E 32 34 22   "192.168.178.24"
0x0050: 7D 0D 0A 0D 0A FE 27 00 D4 13 68 34 6E 7C BE 02   }.....'...h4n|..
0x0060: 01 06 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 FD A5 06 93 A4 E2 4F B1   ....L.........O.
0x0070: AF CF C6 EB 07 64 78 25 27 13 4C B9 8E 0D 0A FE   .....dx%'.L.....
0x0080: 27 03 12 3B 6A 1A 84 98 B6 02 01 06 1A FF 4C 00   '..;j.........L.
0x0090: 02 15 B5 B1 82 C7 EA B1 49 88 AA 99 B5 C1 51 70   ........I.....Qp
0x00A0: 08 D9 00 01 00 02 E1 0D 0A FE 28 00 54 60 09 E1   ..........(.T`..
0x00B0: 38 45 CC 02 01 06 03 03 9F FE 17 16 9F FE 02 38   8E.............8
0x00C0: 58 38 50 52 6D 42 51 69 65 73 00 00 01 59 84 6C   X8PRmBQies...Y.l
0x00D0: 32 E4 0D 0A FE 18 00 F4 F9 51 BA 43 26 BE 02 01   2........Q.C&...
0x00E0: 1A 0B FF 4C 00 09 06 03 F1 00 00 00 61 0D 0A FE   ...L........a...
0x00F0: 27 03 D7 A0 94 8A 24 A2 C6 02 01 06 1A FF 4C 00   '.....$.......L.
0x0100: 02 15 E2 C5 6D B5 DF FB 48 D2 B0 60 D0 F5 A7 10   ....m...H..`....
0x0110: 96 E0 00 00 00 00 21 0D 0A FE 27 00 D4 13 68 34   ......!...'...h4
0x0120: 6E 7C BE 02 01 06 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 FD A5 06 93   n|......L.......
0x0130: A4 E2 4F B1 AF CF C6 EB 07 64 78 25 27 13 4C B9   ..O......dx%'.L.
0x0140: 8E 0D 0A FE 18 00 F4 F9 51 BA 43 26 BE 02 01 1A   ........Q.C&....
0x0150: 0B FF 4C 00 09 06 03 F1 00 00 00 61 0D 0A FE 18   ..L........a....
0x0160: 00 F4 F9 51 BA 43 26 BE 02 01 1A 0B FF 4C 00 09   ...Q.C&......L..
0x0170: 06 03 F1 00 00 00 61 0D 0A FE 27 00 D4 13 68 34   ......a...'...h4
0x0180: 6E 7C BE 02 01 06 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 FD A5 06 93   n|......L.......
0x0190: A4 E2 4F B1 AF CF C6 EB 07 64 78 25 27 13 4C B9   ..O......dx%'.L.
0x01A0: 8E 0D 0A FE 27 03 D7 A0 94 8A 24 A2 C6 02 01 06   ....'.....$.....
0x01B0: 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 E2 C5 6D B5 DF FB 48 D2 B0 60   ..L.....m...H..`
0x01C0: D0 F5 A7 10 96 E0 00 00 00 00 21 0D 0A FE 28 00   ..........!...(.
0x01D0: 54 60 09 E1 38 45 CC 02 01 06 03 03 9F FE 17 16   T`..8E..........
0x01E0: 9F FE 02 38 58 38 50 52 6D 42 51 69 65 73 00 00   ...8X8PRmBQies..
0x01F0: 01 59 84 6C 32 E4 0D 0A FE 27 03 D7 A0 94 8A 24   .Y.l2....'.....$
0x0200: A2 C3 02 01 06 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 E2 C5 6D B5 DF   .......L.....m..
0x0210: FB 48 D2 B0 60 D0 F5 A7 10 96 E0 00 00 00 00 24   .H..`..........$
0x0220: 0D 0A FE 18 00 F4 F9 51 BA 43 26 BE 02 01 1A 0B   .......Q.C&.....
0x0230: FF 4C 00 09 06 03 F1 00 00 00 61 0D 0A FE 25 00   .L........a...%.
0x0240: 12 3B 6A 1A 85 49 B7 02 01 06 03 03 F5 FE 14 FF   .;j..I..........
0x0250: D2 00 01 01 1D 58 90 F4 2F 33 8E D7 39 BC AC 22   .....X../3..9.."
0x0260: 50 6F 61 0D 0A FE 27 00 D4 13 68 34 6E 7C BE 02   Poa...'...h4n|..
0x0270: 01 06 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 FD A5 06 93 A4 E2 4F B1   ....L.........O.
0x0280: AF CF C6 EB 07 64 78 25 27 13 4C B9 8E 0D 0A FE   .....dx%'.L.....
0x0290: 18 00 F4 F9 51 BA 43 26 BB 02 01 1A 0B FF 4C 00   ....Q.C&......L.
0x02A0: 09 06 03 F1 00 00 00 64 0D 0A                     .......d..
0x02AA:
```

The repeated `8X8PRmBQies` is fairly obvious (the first one has the first 8 at the end of the previous line of output).  The sequence `h4n|` appears multiple times too; so does the hex sequence `51 BA 43 26` (`Q.C&`), and the hex sequence `64 78 25 27 13 4C` (`dx%'.L`).

Without knowledge of the context in which this was spotted, it may be hard to do much more with the data.  If I was going to work on it, I'd split the information on the `0D 0A` line endings, and analyze the lines separately.  (AFAICS, neither `0D` nor `0A` appears except in the sequence `0D 0A`.)